# How to get id.value of selected option in ReactiveForm?

Tags: angular

I have reactive form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      classNumber: [null, [Validators.required]],
});
```

Template is:

```
<mat-select formControlName="classNumber"
placeholder="{{ 'select_period' | translate }}">
  <mat-option [value]="c.classNumber"
     *ngFor="let c of filter.data.classNumbers">{{ c.classNumber }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

How to get name of selected `[value]="c.classNumber"`?

Comment: doesn't `this.form.get('classNumber').value` give you the value?

Comment: It returns me value, but I need name of selected value, this: `{{ c.classNumber }}`

Comment: Can you provide a working stackblitz of the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component you can use `this.form.get('classNumber').value` to get the current value of the select. You would need to have some sort of a trigger to run this code, such as a button click for example.

If you wanted to get the values out of the form as the options are changed, you can use a `valueChanges` subscription like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form.get('classNumber').valueChanges.subscribe(
    (value) => console.log(value) // Or whatever code you wanted to run
  );
}
```

Now, every time the option is changed in your select, the value of the control will be logged to the console, or whatever code you wanted to run in your subscription will be fired.

Comment: I dont need value, I need to get name of value, this: `{{ c.classNumber }}`

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I fully understand. The value that you get from the above code will be the equivalent of `c.classNumber`. Is the name a different part of your code? Do you have a separate array or object that contains names paired against classNumber?